# Javascript adding event listener with custom callback?

Tags: javascript, events, listeners

So I am making a game and I want everything to be dynamic so I can use it to make other things. I'm trying to set the event listener callback to a custom callback. I'm just testing it with keydown for now, but when I push my keys, nothing outputs in the console:

Here is the registerKeyListener function:

```
function registerKeyListener(id, type, callback){
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener(type, callback, false);
}
```

Here is how I call it:

```
registerKeyListener("game", "keyDown", move);
```

Where move is:

```
function move(){
    console.log("move function called");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function works. The event is `keydown`, not `keyDown`.

[See demo of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/B5Xkn/1/).

Though there can be events with upper case letters, all the usual ones are lower case only. Check here for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events

Comment: Oh thank you, I guess I should've caught that. I feel like an idiot right now.

Comment: @Zachrip Happens more often than we expect. I saw it because, guess... has happened to me before :)